# DataType mismatch in criteria expression C# visual studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ms-access

I'm using visual studio 2010,C# and access database. I am trying to store datetime.now into database which is working fine in my old form but in the new form it shows me error. I had use this way

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into empl values(@DateJobFinished)),cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("DateJobFinished", OleDbType.Date);
cmd.Parameters["DateJobFinished"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

then I had tried DBDate

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into empl values(@DateJobFinished),cn);
cmd.Parameters.Add("DateJobFinished", OleDbType.DBDate);
cmd.Parameters["DateJobFinished"].Value = DateTime.Now;
```

Then I had tried it from forum

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateJobFinished", datetimefordatabase(DateTime.Now));

 private DateTime datetimefordatabase(DateTime d)
    {
        return new DateTime(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day);
    }
```

But none of above works. I had checked everything but I don't know it's not working in the new form.and in old form works fine.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("DateJobFinished", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTime.Now.Date` should work as along as the target column is a DateTime type

Comment: Nope its not, I don't know why. as, on my old form its works fine. but in new form its works sometime and start giving me the error.and in access it have datatype Date/Time. thanks for your reply @Plutonix

Answer (score 0):

You miss the field name and a closing quote :

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("insert into empl ( datefieldname ) values( @date )", cn);
```

Comment: closing quote missed in copy paste. and you can also write query in the way I had written(Without datefield).

Comment: OK, but please edit your code. So you have only one field in the table?